# Error when calling Django Rest Framework ModelSerializer update when uploading a file

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class Image(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/')

class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('file', )

class ImageView(APIView):

    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser, MultiPartParser, )

    def post(self, request):
        image = Image.objects.get(pk=1)
        serializer = ImageSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.update(instance=image,validated_data=serializer.data)


            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

using httpie to test the functionality:
http --form POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/image/ 'file'@testimage/test.jpg

throws the error:
'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'url'

when calling

```
serializer.update(instance=image,validated_data=serializer.data)
```

Am I using ModelSerialzier correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is a bug in DRF and will be fixed in DRF 3.2.0 release. Check this Github ticket.
https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/2759

This is happening because the file object sent in the request being unsaved does not have the `.url` attribute associated with it.